# React: How to select all text in textarea

Tags: reactjs

I am following a tutorial and trying to add a bit of my own code while doing so. I want to make all the text in the text area become selected when the user clicks edit. I am unable to do so because whatever I try returns undefined.

```
selectText: function(){
    this.refs.newText.select();
},



renderNormal: function(){
            return (
                <div className="commentContainer">
                    <div className="commentText">{this.props.children}</div>
                    <button onClick={this.edit} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
                    <button onClick={this.remove} className="button-danger">Remove</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
```

Comment: What version of react are you using? if you console.log(this.refs) what gets returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using React < 14.0.0, you'll need to use `getDOMNode()` before `select()`. This has been optimized in newer versions. Here's an example with React 0.13.3.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleEdit = this.selectText.bind(this);
  }
  selectText() {
    this.refs.newText.getDOMNode().select();
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="commentContainer">
        <textarea ref="newText" defaultValue="Hello World!"></textarea>
        <button className="button-success">Save</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleEdit}>Edit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Here's the same example with React 15.1.0.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.newText = {};
    this.handleEdit = this.selectText.bind(this);
  }
  selectText() {
    this.newText.select();
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="commentContainer">
        <textarea ref={(newText) => this.newText = newText} defaultValue="Hello World!"></textarea>
        <button className="button-success">Save</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleEdit}>Edit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your code you don't have any textarea, nor do you have any element assigned with the ref `newText` - are you missing some code here? In order to access `this.refs.newText` you need to have `ref="newText"` assigned to one of your elements on render. The other answer by Fabian Schultz shows the proper usage of ref assignment in a render method.